# In UML can we use Extension Points with Include Usecases?

Tags: uml, use-case

Let's assume that there is a UseCase called "Start Pattern Recognition". But when stating pattern recognition, it's mandatory to either to train a new model or import existing (pre trained) model. One of those option must be performed. I tried to represent that in UML as shown below (I used Includes instead of Extends since it's mandatory to perform either one of this UseCases). But I'm not sure whether it is correct to use "Extension Points" with Include UseCases. Is this correct or Is there any other way to do this?

[image: UML Extension Point]

Comment: That's probably not correct (see http://www.uml-diagrams.org/use-case-extend.html#extension-point). To me it looks like you have 2 main use cases `Train New Model` and `Train Existing Model` where both of them re-use (`<<include>>`) some common things like `Start Pattern Recognition`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't correct; there is no analogous concept to extension points for includes in the UML spec.  As xmojmr has very correctly stated, you really have your inclusion backwards.

This is easy to do, because it's easy to get caught up thinking about the order that use cases occur in over time.  The use case diagram doesn't have anything to do with time; it just states what things a system does, who or what interacts with it and what uses what.

When you are ready to think about the flow of a use case, think about it in terms of an activity diagram.  Also, look at the idea of a "use case narrative", which documents the behavior of the use case.

By the way, extension points in a use case diagram are optional.